# Убрать дергание при скрытии текста

Tags: javascript, html, css

Скрипт скрывает длинный текст и ставит ссылку для открытия. 
Как убрать, чтобы при нажатии по ссылке "скрыть", текст убрался без своеобразного замедления и чтобы текст который был открыт не сдвигался вниз

```js
! function (a) {
 a.fn.truncate = function (b) {
  var c = {
    length: 286,
    minTrail: 0,
    moreText: "читать",
    lessText: "скрыть",
    ellipsisText: " ..."
   },
   b = a.extend(c, b);
  return this.each(function () {
   obj = a(this);
   var k = obj.html();
   if (k.length > b.length + b.minTrail && -1 != (g = k.indexOf(" ", b.length))) {
    var g = k.indexOf(" ", b.length),
     f = k.substring(0, g),
     e = k.substring(g, k.length - 1);
    obj.html(f + '<span class="truncate_ellipsis">' + b.ellipsisText + '</span><span  class="truncate_more">' + e + "</span>"), obj.find(".truncate_more").css("display", "none"), obj.append('<span class="clearboth"><a href="#" class="truncate_more_link">' + b.moreText + "</a></span>");
    var h = a(".truncate_more_link", obj),
     d = a(".truncate_more", obj),
     j = a(".truncate_ellipsis", obj);
    h.click(function () {
     return h.text() == b.moreText ? (d.show("normal"), h.text(b.lessText), j.css("display", "none")) : (d.hide("normal"), h.text(b.moreText), j.css("display", "inline")), !0
    })
   }
  })
 }
}(jQuery), $().ready(function () {
 $(".tip").truncate({
  length: 286,
  minTrail: 0,
  moreText: "читать",
  lessText: "скрыть",
  ellipsisText: " ..."
 })
});
```

```css
.tip a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tip">очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста;очень много текста</div>
```

Comment: Напишите про браузер, а то в Chrome все плавно работает.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Браузер - Мозила Фирефокс

Comment: На открытом тексте выдает автоматом display: inline-block; и сталкивает его вниз от исходного

Comment: Дёргается в Хроме.